# Special letters displaying as HTML entities in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to send information (name and email) from one form to another form on another page. The problem is that when the information is sent to the second form, any special letters (like å, ä, ö etc.) are displayed as HTML entities (ö becomes &ouml). I'm a beginner coder and did not build the form that sends the information myself, but I believe it's sent with jQuery. The form is validated, serialized and then decoded before it's sent to the other page. Code is below:

```
/*Form Submit*/ 
$('#button').click(function(){

  if (validateForm()) {
    var data = $("#form-signup").serialize();
    var dataDecoded = decodeURI(data);
    var regUrl = 'mypage.com/registration' + '&' + dataDecoded;
    $("#link").attr("href", regUrl);


  if (($('#checkBox').is(':checked'))) {
      $('#checkBox').css('outline', 'none');
      return true;
      } else {    
        $('#checkBox').css('outline', '1px solid red');
        $('#checkbox-message').next().addClass('checkbox-error');
        $('#checkbox-message').next().text('Please Tick the Agree to Terms of Use');
        return false;
        }
   }
});
```

In console all letters and special characters look alright, as well as in the URL on the second page. The URL becomes something like:

mypage.com/registration?&firstName=Björn&lastName=Björngård&email=bjorn%40mail.com.

But in the actual form the name displays like: Bj&amp';ouml';rn Bj&amp';ouml';rng&amp';aring';rd. (Without the ') . Email displays correct.

Any idea if the problem is with sending the information or receiving?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function :

`unescape(Your_String_Here);`

its a pure JavaScript function url decodes any value

see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_unescape)

**Update**

Check this as well:

```
var parser = new DOMParser;
var dom = parser.parseFromString(your_string);
var decodedString = dom.body.textContent;

alert(decodedString);
```